# LEFT JOIN with WHERE doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have 2 tables called **photos** and **przedmioty**:

[image: http://imgur.com/1rfIezV]

I want to get all *path* from table **photos** and one *cena* from table **przedmioty**, but only there, where *id_gal* from **photos** is the same like *id_gal* in **przedmioty**. I have a small trouble, because in the table photos, there are many the same **id_gal** and in the table przedmioty there is only one time the same *id_gal* like in table **photos**.

What I already tried:

```
SELECT a.path, b.cena
    FROM photos a 
    LEFT JOIN przedmioty b 
    ON a.id_gal = b.id_gal
    WHERE id_gal = ?
```

I'm not the best in subqueries, but maybe it is possible with subquery similar to this one:

```
SELECT a.path FROM photos a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT b.cena 
    FROM przedmioty b
    WHERE a.id_gal = b.id_gal
)
```

I know that the second example, using subquery is ugly and doen't work, however I had to show something like that, to get your help. 
I accept an answer and give thumb ups for every little help.

Tables again:

[http://imgur.com/1rfIezV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEugs.jpg)

Comment: prefix `id_gal` with the table alias, otherwise it's ambiguous as both tables contain that column

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the id_gal column after where with the table alias as follow.

SELECT a.path, b.cena
    FROM photos a 
    LEFT JOIN przedmioty b 
    ON a.id_gal = b.id_gal
    WHERE **a.id_gal** = ?

Comment: Is there a difference between a.id_gal and b.id_gal after a WHERE?

Comment: Yes. **a.id_gal** refer to the photos table id_gal attribute and **b.id_gal** refer to the przedmioty table id_gal attribute.    ----@WojciechGlapa

Comment: I understand that, but I rather had on mind why the results are the same.

Comment: Ya.. Result is same because the value in a.id_gal and b.id_gal is same. But when we write id_gal rather than a.id_gal or b.id_gal the compiler throw an error because it confuse on which table id_gal it should pick for checking the where clause..